# Android Custom Magnifier Offset Issue

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, imageview, android-custom-view

I want to create a Magnifier for bitmap . I have created it succesfully , but the only thing is it does not show the exact view which is touched , it shows nearby view . I have used a imageView and created a custom class for the same .
In onDraw()

```
            if (mShouldDrawMagnifier) {
                mMagnifierMatrix.reset()
                mMagnifierMatrix.setScale(MAGNIFICATION, MAGNIFICATION)
                mMagnifierMatrix.preTranslate(
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x + (mTouchPoint.x - paddingLeft.toFloat() - marginStart.toFloat()) * MAGNIFICATION * -1.0f,
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.y + (mTouchPoint.y - paddingTop.toFloat() - marginTop.toFloat()) * MAGNIFICATION * -1.0f
                )
                val magnifierX =
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x + (mTouchPoint.x - paddingLeft.toFloat() - marginRight.toFloat()) * MAGNIFICATION * -1.0f

                val magnifierY =
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.y + (mTouchPoint.y - paddingTop.toFloat() - marginTop.toFloat()) * MAGNIFICATION * -1.0f
                if (mCurrentMagnifierAlpha < 255) {
                    mMagnifierPaint.alpha = mCurrentMagnifierAlpha
                    mMagnifierCrosshair.alpha = mCurrentMagnifierAlpha
                    mMagnifierBorderPaint.alpha = mCurrentMagnifierAlpha
                    mCurrentMagnifierAlpha += 17

                    postInvalidateDelayed(
                        50,
                        (mMagnifierDestPoint.x).toInt(),
                        (mMagnifierDestPoint.y).toInt(),
                        (mMagnifierDestPoint.x).toInt(),
                        (mMagnifierDestPoint.y).toInt()
                    )
                } else {
                    mCurrentMagnifierAlpha = 255
                    mMagnifierPaint.alpha = mCurrentMagnifierAlpha
                    mMagnifierCrosshair.alpha = mCurrentMagnifierAlpha
                    mMagnifierBorderPaint.alpha = mCurrentMagnifierAlpha
                }
                mMagnifierPaint.shader.setLocalMatrix(mMagnifierMatrix)
                canvas!!.drawCircle(
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x, mMagnifierDestPoint.y, mMagnifierRadius,
                    mMagnifierPaint
                )
                canvas.drawCircle(
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x, mMagnifierDestPoint.y, mMagnifierRadius,
                    mMagnifierBorderPaint
                )
                canvas.drawLine(
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x - mMagnifierRadius,
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.y,
                    mMagnifierRadius + mMagnifierDestPoint.x,
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.y,
                    mMagnifierCrosshair
                )
                canvas.drawLine(
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x,
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.y - mMagnifierRadius,
                    mMagnifierDestPoint.x,
                    mMagnifierRadius + mMagnifierDestPoint.y,
                    mMagnifierCrosshair
                )
            }
```

For setting Magnifier Points above my image , I have done it this way .

```
   @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private fun setMagnifierPoints(xTouch: Float, yTouch: Float) {

        val topY = top
        getLocationInWindow(intArrayOf(0, 0))
        mTouchPoint.x = xTouch
        mTouchPoint.y = yTouch
        val display = (context.getSystemService("window") as WindowManager).defaultDisplay
        val size = Point()
        display.getSize(size)
        val screenWidth = size.x
        val screenHeight = size.y
        val halfX = mMeasuredRect!!.width().toFloat() / 2.0f
        val breakPoint = if (mMagnifierLeftSide) {
            halfX - 15.0f
        } else {
            halfX + 15.0f
        }
        if (mMagnifierLeftSide && xTouch < breakPoint || !mMagnifierLeftSide && xTouch > breakPoint) {
            mCurrentMagnifierAlpha = 0
            mMagnifierLeftSide = !mMagnifierLeftSide
        }
        if (mMagnifierLeftSide) {
            mMagnifierDestPoint.x =
                mMagnifierOffsetX.toFloat() + mMagnifierRadius - ((screenWidth - mMeasuredRect!!.width()) / 2).toFloat()
        } else {
            mMagnifierDestPoint.x =
                ((mMeasuredRect!!.width() + screenWidth) / 2 - mMagnifierOffsetX).toFloat() - mMagnifierRadius
        }
        mMagnifierDestPoint.y =
            mMagnifierOffsetY.toFloat() + mMagnifierRadius - ((screenHeight - mMeasuredRect!!.height()) / 2).toFloat()
        val clipAmount =
            mMagnifierDestPoint.y - mMagnifierRadius + topY.toFloat() - mMagnifierPadding

        if (clipAmount < 0.0f) {
            val pointF = mMagnifierDestPoint
            pointF.y -= clipAmount
        }
}
```

It looks something like this , the Point in consideration is the bottom right Point .
[image]

As you can see, in the magnifier it shows that it is at the edge but in the actual image , it shows  it is bit far